# why is a ring ideal not called a filter

Tags: category-theory, ideals, order-theory, duality-theorems, filters

A ring ideal can be characterized by the two rules:
$$(a\in I) \wedge (a ~ \textrm{divides} ~ b) \implies b \in I$$
$$ a,b \in I \implies \textrm{gcd}(a,b) \in I$$
(the usual definition states $a,b \in \implies a+b \in I$ instead of gcd, but it's equivalent by the Bezout's identity)

When we use the notation $(b \le a) :\Leftrightarrow (a ~ \textrm{divides} ~ b)$ and thus also consistently $a \vee b := \textrm{gcd}(a,b)$, we get exactly the definition of an ideal in a poset.

However, the usual convention is the opposite, using $(a \le b) :\Leftrightarrow (a ~ \textrm{divides} ~ b)$ and thus also $a \wedge b := \textrm{gcd}(a,b)$. And in this case we obtain the dual of an ideal, called a filter.

Then my question is, why we don't call ring ideals "ring filters" instead? Isn't it unconsistent to call them ideals? Shouldn't the poset versions of filter and ideal definitions be interchanged in order to get back the consistency?

**Edit: Arnaud D. found what is wrong. My definition of an ideal is not equivalent to the original one. Indeed, there are ideals that are not principal ideals.**

Comment: The term "ideal" was first used for rings, so, if anything, it's lattice ideals that should be renamed. However, the term for lattices [was explicitly based on the ring case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_(order_theory)#History). The formulation of each notion described [here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/ideal) seems more compelling.

Comment: Are you sure your definition is equivalent to the usual one ?

Comment: @ArnaudD. Oops, it seems that by my definition all ideals end up being principal ideals... something is wrong indeed.

Comment: $\gcd(a,b)$ is defined and exists in any ring?